# HTML5 Video tag with no source?

Tags: video, html

Is there any defined behaviour if I have an HTML5 VIDEO tag but include neither a SRC attribute nor SOURCE tags inside the element? Would this still be valid HTML, and if so, what should the (HTML5 capable) browser do - ignore the element or display it's contents?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is defined behavior; HTML5 is trying to provide defined behavior for any case in which it could make a difference between browsers, to reduce incompatibility, even when dealing with invalid documents.

From my reading of [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#video), it looks like it is invalid to have no `src` attribute or `source` element:

> Content model:
>   If the
>   element has a src attribute:
>   transparent, but with no media element
>   descendants.
>   If the element does not
>   have a src attribute: one or more
>   source elements, then, transparent,
>   but with no media element
>   descendants.

This seems to indicate to me that it must have either a `src` attribute or a `source` child element. But both the [Validator.nu](http://validator.nu/) and the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org) seem to think this is a valid document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Video test</title>
<video></video>
```

Regardless of whether it's valid, the behavior is defined in the [resource selection algorithm](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#concept-media-load-algorithm) as follows:

> ⌛ Otherwise the media element has
>   neither a src attribute nor a source
>   element child: set the networkState to
>   NETWORK_EMPTY, and abort these steps;
>   the synchronous section ends.

This implies a ready state of [`HAVE_NOTHING`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#dom-media-have_nothing)

> `HAVE_NOTHING` (numeric value 0)
>   No information regarding the media
>   resource is available. No data for the
>   current playback position is
>   available. Media elements whose
>   networkState attribute is
>   `NETWORK_EMPTY` are always in the
>   `HAVE_NOTHING` state.

In that state, the video is represented by its [poster frame](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#dom-video-poster), or nothing:

> When no video data is available (the
>   element's readyState attribute is
>   either `HAVE_NOTHING`, or
>   `HAVE_METADATA` but no video data has
>   yet been obtained at all), the video
>   element represents either the poster
>   frame, or nothing.

When it's represented by nothing, that means it appears as just a generic box; like a `div`, that can be styled but has no intrinsic display of its own, though it will be the width and height specified by its `width` and `height` attributes. [For example](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Cvideo%20width%3D100%20height%3D100%20style%3D%22border-width%3A%201px%3B%20border-color%3Ablack%3B%20border-style%3A%20solid%3B%20background%3A%20green%22%3E%0Afoobar%0A%3C%2Fvideo%3E):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<video width=100 height=100 
       style="border-width: 1px; border-color:black; border-style: solid; 
              background: green">
foobar
</video>
```

Note that it does not display its content, in browsers that support the `video` tag. Content within the `video` tag, other than the `source` elements, is intended to be fallback content displayed only by older browsers that don't support the `video` element:

> Content may be provided inside the
>   video element. User agents should not
>   show this content to the user; it is
>   intended for older Web browsers which
>   do not support video, so that legacy
>   video plugins can be tried, or to show
>   text to the users of these older
>   browsers informing them of how to
>   access the video contents.

Comment: I'd add that the default size, if not set by width/height attributes or CSS, is 300x150.

Answer (score -2):

I guess the content would be displayed if the video wasn't found, and in your case it wasn't even specified. But I also assume that the src attribute is mandatory for the tag to make sense, like an img tag. So it wouldn't be *valid* without it, but it could default to linking an non-existing video..

It's important to remember that browsers will implement things differently, regardless of specifications, so you'll just have to wait and see.