# How to change a video when I press on a image with onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I´m a newbie in JS and i have written some code but it doesnt work.

I want to change the video in the background, when i click on a image.

Heres my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="slide">
    
     <video src="videos\Hair - 43633.mp4" class="source" class="video_item" id="videos" autoplay muted loop controls> </video>
    
     <ul id="video_navigation">
    
          <li onclick="videoUrl('videos\Hair - 43633.mp4')"> <img src="image\moon-6616172_1920.jpg" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav" > </li> 
          <li onclick="videoUrl('videos\Road - 81676.mp4')"> <img src="image\background-313415.jpg" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav" > </li> 
          <li onclick="videoUrl('videos\Skyscrapers - 80724.mp4')"> <img src="image\blue-5457731_1920.jpg" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav" > </li> 
          <li onclick="videoUrl('videos\Tunnel - 84938.mp4')"> <img src="image\add-plus-button.png" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav" > </li>
                        
     </ul>
    
</div>
```

JS:

```
function videoUrl(src_video)
{
    document.querySelector(".source").src = src_video;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Including any error messages you see would be helpful. I suspect this may be your issue: [href syntax : is it okay to have space in file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172579/href-syntax-is-it-okay-to-have-space-in-file-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't set *src* to video tag directly**.

Instead use a `<source src="foo">`  tag inside the video tag. [HTML5 Video tag with no source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944271/html5-video-tag-with-no-source)

- You forgot to close img tag but it's not a big problem, just don't forget it.

**I used video.poster to display the proof**.

```js
function videoUrl(src_video) {
  alert(src_video)
  document.querySelector(".source").poster = src_video;
  // I used poster the proof that it's working
  // document.querySelector('source').src = src_video
};
```

```html
<div id="slide">

  <video class="source" class="video_item" id="videos" autoplay muted loop controls>
    <!-- <source src="foo" /> -->
  </video>

  <ul id="video_navigation">

    <li onclick="videoUrl('https://i.pinimg.com/564x/30/cd/77/30cd77b3532c329568b2029ca4f5f398.jpg')"> <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/30/cd/77/30cd77b3532c329568b2029ca4f5f398.jpg" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav" width="128px" height="128px"/> </li>
    <li onclick="videoUrl('https://i.pinimg.com/564x/bf/36/9b/bf369b962ce5ed2cb5cdd6589327fe28.jpg')"> <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/bf/36/9b/bf369b962ce5ed2cb5cdd6589327fe28.jpg" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav"  width="128px" height="128px"/> </li>
    <li onclick="videoUrl('https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a3/6a/5a/a36a5aa6533b4a1f570eb571bf17f89d.jpg')"> <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a3/6a/5a/a36a5aa6533b4a1f570eb571bf17f89d.jpg" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav"  width="128px" height="128px"/> </li>
    <li onclick="videoUrl('https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2a/82/23/2a8223502f356fc936398307912b3313.jpg')"> <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2a/82/23/2a8223502f356fc936398307912b3313.jpg" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav"  width="128px" height="128px"/> </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: So that sort of works but my video isn´t loading.